# How does assetic.twig_directory_resource.kernel work?

Tags: symfony

I see in liiptheme bundle it tries to modifies the list of folders that assetic should look for resources, but I don't see it being called any where at all.

I'm trying to find out why assetic doesn't load the theme resources on my project (I want to place resources out of any bundle, for example app/Resources/views/themeName/public/js/abc.js) and it seems like this assetic.twig_directory_resource.kernel is holding the key to the question. I just cannot seem to find where it is called/used at all.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to move out of the bundle-structure. Your assets... or templates ... or both?

Comment: hi nifr, I'm trying to move both actually if possible.

Comment: I got around the issue I tried to solve, but still interested to know exactly how assetic_twig_directory_resource.kernel is being used.